# Swift 2 optional guard on string

Tags: swift2, guard-statement

I'm dealing with an issue in swift 2.0

I get a json file from an API and i'm trying to unwrap some strings out of it.

Sometimes this json gives me a string with the street name of a venue but sometimes not.
So when i'm trying this

```
var street = arrRes[indexPath.row]["venueLocation"]!["street"] as! String
```

It always crashes my app saying it is nil. When i comment it my app runs perfect but it doesnt show the street.
Any idea of how to unwrap the string without having any issue with `nil` ??

If tried this code

```
var street = arrRes[indexPath.row]["venueLocation"]!["street"] as! String 

if street == "" {
   street = "n/a"
}
```

But it failed also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any time you force unwrap with `!` you run the risk of crashing where a value is nil.  Instead you can try unwrapping like:

```
guard let venueDictionary = arrRes[indexPath.row]["venueLocation"] as? [String:AnyObject], let street = venueDictionary["street"] as? String else {
   //You don't have a street string, fail gracefully 
}
print(street)//Now you can use street safely as a string here
```

Comment: i have to write `return` inside the `else` ??

Comment: @KwnstantinosNatsios Yes, or `fatalError()` or `break` or something to exit the scope, which is what the `guard` statement does. If you don't want to early exit or use `guard`, then you can change it to:  `if let venueDictionary = arrRes[indexPath.row]["venueLocation"] as? [String:AnyObject], let street = venueDictionary["street"] as? String {
   print(street) //Now you can use street safely as a string here
}`

Comment: I'm trying to then to send this variable to another View Controller. but at the certain cell that has the `nil` street it doesnt let me go inside the next view controller... but with other cells that have normal street i dont have any issue.

Comment: @KwnstantinosNatsios  How about something like this: `if let venueDictionary = arrRes[indexPath.row]["venueLocation"] as? [String:AnyObject], let street = venueDictionary["street"] as? String { otherViewController.streetText = street } else { otherViewController.streetText = ""}`

Comment: @KwnstantinosNatsios  Great!  :)